# Constructor inside the static block

Tags: java, constructor

Is it possible to write the constructor inside the static block of code.

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: Why do you need this? It's real question or just for fun?

Comment: You want an instance constructor inside the static constructor ?

Comment: I really have trouble believing the kind of stuff people come up with. Voting to close because obviously nobody (including the OP) has a clue as to what is actually being asked here.

Comment: Damodar it helps if you can elaborate your question with actual requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Constructors are always non-static, and you have access for only static fields and members in static block.

As for static block itself, it is commonly used to do some class initialization, as this code is added to every constructor of a class.

Comment: The static block isn't "added to every constructor of a class" - rather it gets run once (in a static context) when the class is loaded.  You might be thinking of [*instance* initialiser](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#246032) blocks, which are like the static block but without the `static` keyword.

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle, thank you for the correction, you're absolutely right.

Comment: @Andrzej thanks to you, I actually learnt something new and somewhat useful.

Answer (score 2):

You could invoke a constructor from a static initializer, and you could also restrict access to that constructor such that it was only ever called from there.

```
public class Foo {
    static Foo singleton;

    static {
        singleton = new Foo();
    }
    private Foo() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean writing a constructor for the class, rather than for an instance check this :

http://www.snippetit.com/2009/03/java-static-constructor/

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to have constructor inside static block.